# Rails 5 with coffee and jquery

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm having little trouble with coffee script in rails more so with principle and understanding then with my script alone.

I have such coffee script:

```
->
  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    alert('my test message')
```

which gets compiled to

```
(function() {
  // Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
  // All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
  // You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
  $(function() {
    return $('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(event) {
      return alert('my test message');
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

The problem I have is that event never fires, when I take manually put this portion of compile code in console the event fires, but I have no way to have the outer most function. Am I using this wrong or can someone explain this to me how does call(this) works,so that I can put proper structure in coffee script?

```
  $(function() {
    return $('form').on('click', '.add_fields', function(event) {
      return alert('my test message');
    });
  });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have turbolinks enabled? if so, wrap the `$('form')` bind inside a `turbolinks:load` event listener.

Comment: You are correct it fixed. Still would like to know how the turbolinks impacted this in general. but event works now. Answer below

Comment: Check Turbolinks doc, specially the section about that event listener un particular https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#installing-javascript-behavior. Turbolinks does some thing on the background that makes your website trigger different events in order to provide it's functionality, you can adapt your workflow to use turbolinks or disable it if you don't want it. Read de README to be sure if you really want it before changing your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final coffeescript which is working

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault())
```